# how to get selected auto complete textbox value in jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

Below is my code, how to get selected auto complete textbox value in
JQuery?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script>
             $(function() {
                $( "#data" ).autocomplete("list.jsp")

             });
      </script>  
        <script> 
             $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('#data').on('change', function () {
                        $('#d').html('You selected: ' + this.value);
                    }).change();
                    $('#data').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
                        $('#d').html('You selected: ' + ui.item.value);
                    });
                });

          </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="osave.jsp" name="frm" method="post">
    Customer Name <input type="text" id="data" name="cname">
    <div id="d"></div>
    </form>
```

Textbox autocomplete works, but cant get selected textbox value .
The output is as follows:

> Customer Name:usha
>   You selected: u

Comment: am new for jquery any one help,how to solve this problem.

Comment: any problem for this 2 tag ,<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question more generally, the answer is:

```
select: function( event , ui ) {
    alert( "You selected: " + ui.item.label );
}
```

Complete example :

```
$('#test').each(function(i, el) {
    var that = $(el);
    that.autocomplete({
        source: ['apple','banana','orange'],
        select: function( event , ui ) {
            alert( "You selected: " + ui.item.label );
        }
    });
});
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Type a fruit here: `<input type="text" id="test" />`

Comment: am using this <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

When autocomplete changes a value, it fires a autocompletechange event, not the change event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tags').on('autocompletechange change', function () {
        $('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + this.value);
    }).change();
});
```

Demo: Fiddle

Another solution is to use select event, because the change event is triggered only when the input is blurred

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tags').on('change', function () {
        $('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + this.value);
    }).change();
    $('#tags').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
        $('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + ui.item.value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `ui.item.value` with `ui.item.label` like:

```
$('#data').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
   $('#d').html('You selected: ' + ui.item.label);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tags').on('change', function () {
        $('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + this.value);
    }).change();
    $('#tags').on('blur', function (e, ui) {
        $('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + ui.item.value);
    });
});
```

try this one.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
<script>
             $(function() {
                $( "#data" ).autocomplete({
                 select: function (event, ui) {
                 $('#d').html('You selected: ' + ui.value);                    
                return false;
            }

                })

             });
      </script>
```

Comment: @RamChithra Now check you